# Would like help understanding this Swift hackery

Tags: swift

I bumped into this example of a cool Swift technique without an explanation of how it works or what it does, and even though I've written a decent amount of Swift code, this is so full of intricate Swiftisms it's currently twisting my head around.

If there's someone proficient enough with Swift who doesn't mind dissecting it and discerning its purpose, it would really increase my grasp of the language and its more powerful features, and probably enlighten others as well.

```
extension Array {
    var match : (head: T, tail: [T])? {
       return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil
    }
}

func map<A, B>(f: A -> B, arr: [A]) -> [B] {
    if let (head, tail) = arr.match {
        return [f(head)] + map(f, tail)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh. I've never used Swift before but I think I can read that. What part is giving you problems?

Comment: There are a few questions. I understand how A and B are types and how they're used in map, because they're 'declared' in <A, B>. But I don't understand how T can be used as a type in the computed property in the match function of the Array extension without being explicitly declared, unless perhaps someone saw the Array source code and knows about something under the hood.

Comment: `Array` is a *generic* type and the type place holder used to be `T` in Swift 2. It is called `Element` in Swift 3.

Comment: I wonder why the first method is called `match`, it doesn't look for any match.

Comment: @Sulthan It's used for list-style pattern matching on arrays.

Comment: That code is certainly of theoretical interest, but horribly inefficient, lots of intermediate array are created. You would get the same result using the *existing* `map` method of collection types with `arr.map(f)`.

Comment: @clearlight `T` comes from the original definition of `Array`, yes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extension` to the `Array` type defines a new computed property called `match`. This property is of type `(head: T, tail: [T])?`, so an optional tuple where the first element *(named `head`)* is of type `T` and the second element *(named `tail`)* is of type Array of `T`. `T` is just the generic type for the type of the element that is stored inside of the array (Since `Array` is a generic collection itself).

```
var match : (head: T, tail: [T])? {
   return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil
}
```

This computed property either returns `nil`, if the Array doesn't contain any elements, or it returns a tuple containing the first element of the list (`self[0]` and the tail of the list (everything except for the first element): `Array(self[1..<count])`.

Now that array have this computed property we can make use of it to recursively call a function `f` on the elements of an array and return a new `Array` that contains the results of those function calls. This is what a `map` function does:

```
func map<A, B>(f: A -> B, arr: [A]) -> [B] {
    if let (head, tail) = arr.match {
        return [f(head)] + map(f, tail)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

The mapping function `f` is of [type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174) `A -> B` which means that it maps elements of type `A` to elements of type `B`, therefore `map` has to be passed an array of type `[A]`. Then, using the `match` variable and optional binding we can call `f` on the head of the list `[f(head)]` and put it inside of a new list and then append the result of the recursive `map` call for the rest of the array elements `map(f, tail)`.

To understand the map function they're trying to implement better:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what `f: A -> B` is. I thought `->` was for function return values. It's been awhile since I read the Swift docs. I am going to dig around for this. Unless A has to be a function type, I'm really confused. If it was just a simple type it wouldn't make sense. Like `A -> B`, an int returning a float.

Comment: @clearlight `A -> B` is the type of functions that take an `A` and return a `B`, i.e. `f` is a function from `A` to `B`.

Comment: @clearlight I added that to the answer as well. You can read more about this if you follow that link (on `type`).

Comment: @melpomene I guess it's more common to put a in parens (A), but Swift is probably smart enough to know it *must* be a function `type` because of the `->`